# highcharts heatmap tiles float after resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm using highcharter library in R to create a heatmap (code below). But when I resize my window the chart although adjusts to the new width of the flex container but it when I hover over the tiles they start floating and seem to go back to the previously located position.

Also, FYI if I make a call to chart.redraw() explicitly in console then the floating issue goes away.

```
dat <- datasets::airquality

  shiny::fillRow(
    flex = 1,

    # heatmap
    highcharter::highchart(elementId = 'heatmap_test') %>%
      highcharter::hc_add_series(dat, highcharter::hcaes(y = Month, x = Day, value = Temp),
                                 type = 'heatmap')

)
```

Image of flying tiles on mouse hover after window resize -

[image]

Also, if I disable mouseTracking then the tiles stop flying away and stay where they are supposed to be.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this behavior in the vanilla JS (in my case everything works correctly), so It seems to be a wrapper issue. However, there is a similar flex-related thread on GitHub, that you can check: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6427

Comment: @magdalena i don't think it is an issue with resizing the chart because it does resize according to the window size, the problem is that when I hover over the tiles they fly to a different location. I added a snip of the effect that I'm seeing

Comment: Thank you for adding the details. Unfortunately, since I'm not able to reproduce this issue I don't confirm it as a Highcharts bug. I would suggest contacting directly the wrapper authors on github repository

Comment: Do you think you could make your question reproducible? The current code in your question doesn't create this problem. I'd like to help.

Comment: @Kat you can use the same code snippet above to reproduce the issue if you are using R.

Comment: I did create the plot using your code. However, I'm not seeing the jumping issue you've written about. That's what I meant about reproducing the error. Does the code in your question, as it is, cause the same issue you see with the app?

Comment: Yes, I see the issue using the same code. I'm using highcharts version 9.3.1, what's yours? Could that be the reason for the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the issue is with the highcharts version I'm using i.e. 9.3.1. Looks like there is a bug in that version where it needs to make an explicit call to chart.reflow() to resize the heatmap. I shifted to highcharts 10.0.2 and the issue is now gone.

Comment: I had the same issue, that occured after i resized the window. The github dev version of highcharter in version 0.9.4.9000 now uses HighchartsJS 10.2.0.
But is it not on Cran yet.